# open gitpod without a repo - not starting from a template

Tags: gitpod

is it possible to open gitpod in order to have a fresh and empty enviroment without an existing project or template?

I'd like to manually create a project and issue `gp init` to initialize my enviroment from scratch

and morover, opening an existing repo and modify the gitpod.yml, is it possible to re-execute the enviroment without push the changes and open a new window?

Answer (score 5):

Wait no more.

https://gitpod.new/

Spins up empty environment for you.

Comment: This still asks for a repository, so it’s best to have an empty on created.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best thing you can do is to have an empty repository on your git provider(GitHub/GitLab/or-anything-else) and open that from `New Workspace` button on https://gitpod.io/workspaces

Other than that, please upvote this feature request:
https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/7936